# Selecting duplicates from multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, having

I have a customer_product table where the identifier is the "stock_code".

I then have three tables:

- bom_component
- routing
- material_process

Each of these tables are joined to a customer_product via it's stock_code and contain various other fields.

I'm trying to select customer_products where the records in the other three tables are exactly the same and only return the stock_code of the duplicates.

Any help figuring this out would be great, thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, when I said "where the records in the other tables are the same" I meant:

(taking routing for example)

stock_code  department  sequence
1234            goodsin            1
1234            prep                    2
1234            packing            3
3344            goodsin            1
3344            prep                    2
3344            packing            3
5661            goodsin       1
5661            packing       2

Here the stockcodes 1234 and 3344 would be returned because their records in routing are exact matches.

And I'm using mySQL.

Comment: "where the records in the other three tables are exactly the same" What will this mean? All three table have same structure?

Comment: And if all four tables have the same structure, why are there four tables?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which RDBMS you are using you could use an INTERSECT statement, it's basically like a UNION but only returns rows where there is a match in all the separate SQL statements.

```
SELECT stock_code, price FROM bom_component
INTERSECT
SELECT stock_code, price FROM routing
INTERSECT
SELECT stock_code, price FROM material_process
```

This will return rows where there are duplicates. I have assumed price as a column, but just add in the columns you want to make the unique criteria.